# Regex to get the link in href. [asp.net]

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

hi i got problems to get my regex to work. im working with C# asp.net
i will post the code i use now and what i cant get to work is the second regex to get whatever is in the href="LINK"

thx in advance

```
var textBody = "lorem ipsum... <a href='http://www.link.com'>link</a>";


        var urlTagPattern = new Regex(@"<a.*?href=[""'](?<url>.*?)[""'].*?>(?<name>.*?)</a>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);



        //THIS IS THE REGEX
        var hrefPattern = new Regex(@"HREF={:q}\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);




        var urls = urlTagPattern.Matches(textBody);


        foreach (Match url in urls)
        {

            var hrefs = hrefPattern.Match(url.ToString());


            litStatus.Text = hrefs.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 14):

Welcome to your daily installment of *Don't Use Regex To Parse HTML*. In this edition of *Don't Use Regex To Parse HTML*, we'll be reminding you not to use regex to parse HTML because HTML cannot reliably be parsed by a regex and dozens of valid HTML constructs will break the naïve regex proposed. We won't be mentioning all the additional invalid ones in common use on the web in *Don't Use Regex To Parse HTML* today.

Also in *Don't Use Regex To Parse HTML*, we'll be linking to the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack), a .NET library you can use to parse HTML properly and subsequently extract link URLs reliably in just a couple of lines of code (a very similar example being present on that page).

We hope you have enjoyed today's *Don't Use Regex To Parse HTML*, and look forward to seeing you again tomorrow for another exciting edition of *Don't Use Regex To Parse HTML*, when someone posts another question about using regex to parse HTML. But that's all from *Don't Use Regex To Parse HTML* for now. Bye!

Comment: Was this a canned response you already used somewhere else or you wrote it explicitly? (+1)

Comment: Is it alright to rate answers +1 based on humor (assuming they're correct?) If not, consider me a rebel against the system!

Comment: beautiful.... just beautiful~

Answer (score 1):

The following example searches an input string and prints out all the href="…" values and their locations in the string. It does this by constructing a compiled Regex object and then using a Match object to iterate through all the matches in the string. In this example, the metacharacter \s matches any space character, and \S matches any nonspace character.

' VB

Sub DumpHrefs(inputString As String)

```
Dim r As Regex
Dim m As Match

r = New Regex("href\s*=\s*(?:""(?<1>[^""]*)""|(?<1>\S+))", _
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Compiled)

m = r.Match(inputString)
While m.Success
    Console.WriteLine("Found href " & m.Groups(1).Value _
        & " at " & m.Groups(1).Index.ToString())
    m = m.NextMatch()
End While
```

End Sub

// C#

void DumpHrefs(String inputString)
{

```
Regex r;
Match m;

r = new Regex("href\\s*=\\s*(?:\"(?<1>[^\"]*)\"|(?<1>\\S+))",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Compiled);
for (m = r.Match(inputString); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found href " + m.Groups[1] + " at "
        + m.Groups[1].Index);
}
```

}

Comment: and that was from <a href="http://www.link.com">link</a> so what it did was removed the </a>.. i need to get the http://www.link.com

Answer (score 0):

Second regular expression should be:

```
href=['"](?<link>[^'"]*)
```