# How to parse link of web page from string?

Tags: c#, .net

```
Regex linkParser = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    string rawString = link;
                    foreach (Match m in linkParser.Matches(rawString))
                    {
                        string links = m.Value;
                    }
```

Im trying to parse/get the link from this string:

```
<a href="http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=112190&forum=scoops1"><b>
```

I want to get only this part:

```
http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=112190&forum=scoops1
```

But what im getting in the string links is:

```
http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=112190&forum=scoops1"><b
```

In the end there is left ">

Comment: In an anchor or from the text? If the former `<a href=\"((http|https)://.*?)\">` or use a protper parser like Html Agility Pack

Comment: Please, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/982431) to another similar question.

Comment: Please do not repost the same question again and again, better edit your [old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551077/how-can-i-extract-a-text-from-string-variable-using-regex) and get it reopened if really necessary, but as for your other question, the optimal solution is `NOT TO USE REGEX` but a more suitable tool such as [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), just because `HTML is no regular language`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract href tag from a string in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151037/how-to-extract-href-tag-from-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `\S+` to `[^\"\>]+`

Final string: `\b(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)[^\"\>]+\b`

But this does not only find working links. If your link would be something like `<a href="www.a<not working Link>flupp"><b>`, it would find `www.a<not working Link`.

This expression just finds everything until the next `"` or `>` (if it is a valid HTML-Form and you know that the text between both quotation marks is a normal link, you only should need `"` (what would let the expression become `\b(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)[^\"]+\b`)).

Using this it would find `www.a<not working Link>flupp` which is exactly what stands between both quotation marks.

If you want to forbid more chars you have to edit `[^\"\>]+`.

Btw: I think it could make sense to escape both `/` after `?:https?:`

The reason for that is because you tell him to find all non-whitespace-characters and it should end with a letter. Because this expression is greedy it "eats" as many non-whitespace-characters as possible. `"` and `>` are no whitespace-characters,  and  (TAB) are. `[^\"]+` tells him to get all chars until he finds a `"`. After finding one he will stop.

Answer (score 0):

I found use the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) like some people said to do since HTML is not a regular language. After you have downloaded it considering that this is the only node in the source that contains this text:

```
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hp = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            string source = File.ReadAllText( @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\source.txt" );
            hp.LoadHtml(source);
            var node = hp.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[contains(@href, 'http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=112190&forum=scoops1')]");
            string found = node.Attributes["href"].Value;                        
            Console.WriteLine(found);
```

You can pull your source from anywhere you want, either download via webclient or a local file. This will return: `http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=112190&forum=scoops1`