# jmeter use regex to get link text

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to use jmeters regular expression extractor to catch a link from an HTTP response I have. How do I catch only whats inside the `<a href="TEXT"></a>`? I want the *TEXT*.

```
<a([^>]+)>(.+?)<\/a>
```

The expression above gives me the whole link with the `a` tag and href.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather recommend not using regular expressions for getting data from HTML as `href` attribute may be located in differently, at new line, etc. See the [epic comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) on SO for detailed explanation.

JMeter provides 2 test elements which can be used to extract `href` attribute from HTML page links:

- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)

**XPath Example**

1. Add XPath Extractor as a child of the request (just like Regular Expression Extractor)
2. Configure it as follows:

   - If your response is not XHTML compliant - check `Use Tidy` box
   - Reference name - anything meaningful, i.e. `href`
   - XPath query - `//a/@href`
3. You can refer to extracted link URL as `${href}` anywhere in current thread group.
4. In case of multiple matches URLs can be accessed as `${href_1`} `${href_2}` etc.

For more information on the XPath Extractor see [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide

**CSS/JQuery Example**

1. Add CSS/JQuery Extractor as a child of the request
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference name - any variable name, i.e. `href`
   - CSS/JQuery expression - `a`
   - Attribute - `href`
   - Match no:

     - default is `blank` - will return the first link
     - `any number > 0` - will return match number
     - `0` - will return random link URL
     - `-1` - will return all link URLs and store them as  `${href_1`} `${href_2}` etc.

For CSS/JQuery expressions building information refer to [JSOUP selector syntax guide](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<a[^>]* href="([^"]*)"
```

[regular expression for finding 'href' value of a <a> link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926142/regular-expression-for-finding-href-value-of-a-a-link)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

use group 1 to get the content from tag.

```
<a(?: [^>]+)?>((?:(?!<\/?a[ >]).)*)<\/a>
```

**SEE DEMO:**  http://regex101.com/r/rV3eH6/1