# How to get url with regex?

Tags: regex

I have links like that:

```
 <image xlink:href="/fu/files/ws/31rmeec0ccusmqdh9uacsnu081/client/29/preview/delete.png" id="svg_131" height="24" width="24" y="64.8294" x="96.85564"/>
```

what is the best way to obtain only urls? `/fu/files/ws/31rmeec0ccusmqdh9uacsnu081/client/29/preview/delete.png`

Comment: [Almost duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926142/regular-expression-for-finding-href-value-of-a-a-link) (it's missing the `xlink:` bit, and is targetted at an `a` tag)

Comment: @user4703663 Assuming jQuery, and a javascript environment, yes, but since this question was using regex's and an unknown language/environment, it's not really an appropriate answer...

Comment: @user4703663 It's trivially solvable using regex.  There are downvotes because there is no apparent research effort into finding a suitable one.

Answer (score 1):

Purely regex and considering a programming language or the file format:

```
/href=\"(.+?)\"/
```

See it work here: http://www.regexr.com/3b7kr

Please remember, that there are better ways to go about this if you're going through an XML document.