# How to get href of string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

a 3rd party tool I'm using builds an anchor tag like so..

```
"<a href="http://DevNode/Lists/Publications.aspx#/publication/123">http://DevNode/Lists/Publications.aspx#/publication/123</a>"
```

I need to isolate the href so I can trim it. Currently my pattern of

```
reg = /^(<a\shref=")? http:\/\/DevNode\/Lists\/Publications.aspx#\/publication\/(\d+)/i {lastIndex: 0}
```

will fail to match if the href has a leading space like this

```
"<a href=" http://DevNode/Lists/Publications.aspx#/publication/123"> http://DevNode/Lists/Publications.aspx#/publication/123</a>"
```

Please help

Comment: So add an optional space in the reg exp. Aso seems like it is a bug if it has a leading space

Comment: What about answer here => http://stackoverflow.com/a/15926317/929902 ?

Comment: @epascarello yes I agree, I've reported it to the 3rd party. How do I add an exemption for infinite optional spaces, I'm not familiar with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the `*` quantifier that says "any number of times including zero" combined to the `\s` it will match spaces, newlines or else.

So use `\s+` where a space is required but there might be more than one

And use `\s*` where a space is optional but there might be some

```
reg = /^(<a\s+href=")?\s*http:\/\/DevNode\/Lists\/Publications.aspx#\/publication\/(\d+)/i
```

Comment: i think this is what would be most helpful but it does not seem to work.

Comment: nvm, I was using var reg = new RegExp(pattern, 'i'); to create the pattern and therefor needed to escape the backslash character, Thank you, different from my title but indeed most helpful answer

Answer (score 7):

If you're doing this on a browser the simplest way is to let the browser figure it out:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = yourString;
var href = div.querySelector("a").href;
```

This also has the advantage of resolving it if it's a relative URL. If you don't want that, use `getAttribute` instead:

```
var href = div.querySelector("a").getAttribute("href");
```

Note that if you use `getAttribute`, if the attribute has a leading space, the leading space *will* be in the result; `String#trim` could be useful if you want to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks, This was a helpful approach and works well without jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
var ahref = '<a href="http://DevNode/Lists/Publications.aspx#/publication/123">http://DevNode/Lists/Publications.aspx#/publication/123</a>';
var href = ahref.split('"')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy/fast answer is using jQuery, building the tag, and looking for the href attribute.

```
$('<a href="http://DevNode/Lists/Publications.aspx#/publication/123">http://DevNode/Lists/Publications.aspx#/publication/123</a>')
.attr('href')
```

I'll try to get you the RegExp in a bit. Hang on tight...

And as promissed... here's the RegExp

```js
var text = '<a href="http://DevNode/Lists/Publications.aspx#/publication/123">http://DevNode/Lists/Publications.aspx#/publication/123</a>';
console.log(text.match(/<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href="([^"]*)"/)[1])
```

Comment: jQuery is not tagged in the question. And "I'll try to [answer fully later]" isn't useful.