# regex c# extracting url from <a> tag

Tags: c#, regex, url, extract

I am trying to extract URL from an  tag, however, instead of getting https://website.com/-id1, I am getting  tag link text. Here is my code:

```
string text="<a style=\"font - weight: bold; \" href=\"https://website.com/-id1\">MyLink</a>";

 string parsed = Regex.Replace(text, " <[^>] + href =\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>", "$1 " );

    parsed = Regex.Replace(parsed, "<[^>]+>", "");

    Console.WriteLine(parsed);
```

The result I got was **MyLink** which is not what I want. I want something like

```
https://website.com/-id1
```

Any help or a link will be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @rkun you aren't parsing, you are replacing. Shouldn't you be using `.Match` to capture the URL instead of trying to remove anything *outside* the URL? eg `.Match(text,""href\\s*=\\s*\".*?\"")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression for finding 'href' value of a <a> link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926142/regular-expression-for-finding-href-value-of-a-a-link)

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions can be used in very specific, simple cases with HTML. For example, if the text contains *only* a single tag, you can use `"href\\s*=\\s*\"(?<url>.*?)\""` to extract the URL, eg:

```
var url=Regex.Match(text,"href\\s*=\\s*\"(?<url>.*?)\"").Groups["url"].Value;
```

This pattern will return :

```
https://website.com/-id1
```

This regex doesn't do anything fancy. It looks for `href=` with possible whitespace and then captures anything between the first double quote and the next in a non-greedy manner (`.*?`). This is captured in the named group `url`.

Anything more fancy and things get very complex. For example, supporting both single and double quotes would require special handling to avoid starting on a single and ending on a double quote. The string could multiple `<a>` tags that used both types of quotes.

For complex parsing it would be better to use a library like [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/) or [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

Comment: I want to second the recommendation of [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack). As [the most famous SO answer of all time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) will tell you, mixing regular expressions and HTML is generally a bad idea. Stick to parsing libraries that give you something object-oriented to play around with.

Comment: Thank you @Panagiotis; both for the answer and good insight. I will look into them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var input = "<a style=\"font - weight: bold; \" href=\"https://website.com/-id1\">MyLink</a><a style=\"font - weight: bold; \" href=\"https://website.com/-id2\">MyLink2</a>";
var r = new Regex("<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\".*?>");
var output = r.Matches(input);
var urls = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in output) {
    urls.Add((item as Match).Groups[1].Value);
}
```

It will find all a tags and extract their href values then store it in urls List.

### Explanation

`<a`  match begining of <a> tag
`.*?href=` match anything until href=
`"(.*?)"`match and capture anything inside ""
`.*?>` match end of <a> tag

Comment: Thank. A nice one with a good insight. Can you please give me a positive vote to my question so that I can give positive vote to answers. Right now, I have only 13 reputation, I need 2 more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, highly appreciated :)