# How can I extract from a regex

Tags: c#, regex, request, extract

I would like to extract urls from a regex (not all urls, only some via my regex).

I tried `Regex.Match`

```
string html = request.Get(
    "http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + keyword + "&first=1"
).ToString();
Match urls = Regex.Match(html, "<h2><a href=\"(.*?)\"");
```

it only displays one URL, I would like to have all the URLs

EDIT : for people who have had this problem, here is the solution

```
string pattern = @"<a href=""([^""]+)";
                                Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

                                foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(html))
                                    Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}", match.Value, match.Index);
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input / output please?

Comment: Have you checked the `Regex` documentation for C# ?

Comment: Should be `Regex.Matches` I believe. ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @dvo edited, look the post

Comment: @blitzblade yes but I didn't find anything

Comment: @Cuppyzh Regex.Matches dont work, dont escape the "

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an HTML parser and finding the `a` elements by their location within the document or by their properties?

Comment: @madreflection it's only selenium ?

Comment: I doubt that's a hard limitation.

Comment: Other possible duplicates or solutions: [regular expression for finding 'href' value of a <a> link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15926142), [regex c# extracting url from <a> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42118366).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get all URLs you would need to remove `<h2>` tag.

Try pattern: `<a href="([^"]+)`

Explanation:

`<a href="` - match literally `<a href="`

`([^"]+)` - match one or more of characters other than `"` and store it into first capturing group

In order to get all URLs you need to call `Matches` method and then loop through them using `Groups` property:

```
foreach(var match in Regex.Matches(html, "<a href=\"([^\"]+)")
{
  // get url from first capturing group
  string url = match.Groups[1];
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you ! but look, the regex don't work https://i.imgur.com/h0Uweht.png i can make a screenshot of the errors but my Visual Studio is in French langage

Comment: You need `@` (missing in the answer) on the string to escape quote characters that way: `@"<a href=""([^""]+)"`

Comment: okay thanks ! but the match.Groups dont work (error CS1061)

Comment: @madreflection its good, thank you

Comment: @mrspysix Try updated answer.

Comment: @mrspysix You should accept the answer if it has helped you instead of posting it in an answer :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn how ? sorry

Comment: @mrspysix By checking green check mark on the left side of an answer.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn okay its good