# Select href tags from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a HTML string-variable which is:

```
 <html>
    <body style="margin: 0; background: #e0e0e0; text-align:center;">
        <div style="padding: 0; text-align: left; width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; background: #e0e0e0; ">
            <div style="text-align: center; border-bottom: 10px solid #000; background: #FEDC00; ">
            </div>
            <div style="border: 0; padding: 20px; width: 760px; background: #fff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial; font-size: 12px;">
               </tr></table><hr /><div style="font-weight: bold; width: 45%; text-align: center; float: left;  "> <a style="font-size: 17px;display: block; color: #fff; background: #009900; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px 20px;" href="dabb68d353e3a82315ec6419e4aaa854&url=booking|358137|b4e3bea97e18db09d7878a6010b5b57b">ACCEPT</a></div>
       </div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I get href content?

Comment: [Obligatory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3181933). Use tools intended to parse HTML (e.g. HtmlAgilityPack), not RegEx.

Comment: I suggest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926142/regular-expression-for-finding-href-value-of-a-a-link as a duplicate because both regex (with a working regex!) and HTML parsing solutions are given. The HTML parsing solution is to be preferred.

Comment: href=("|')(.*?("|')) use this regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTMLAgilityPack

```
var docs = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
docs.LoadHtml("YourHTML"); 
string HrefValue= docs.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a").Attributes["href"].Value;
```