# Regex - extract href of html tag <a>

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex:

```
(?=<a .*href=")(.+)(?=".*>My Text<\/a>)
```

With this, I try to extract `href` value from an specific HTML tag `<a>` from an `HTML`.

Let's say I have this `HTML`:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
     <a class="..." href="..." ..="..">My Text</a>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

With my regex I get `<a class="..." href="..." ..="..`(stop before `">`), but I want only `href` value.

**Edit:** this answer: [regular expression for finding 'href' value of a <a> link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926142/regular-expression-for-finding-href-value-of-a-a-link) don't help me. With that regex I get all tags `<a>` with all attributes of tag.

Comment: Is the format always fixed or it can change? can you post the whole example

Comment: @Shivaraj format of `<a>`? Do you mean about order of attributes? If yes, not, is not fixed.

Comment: @NullPointerException that regex don't find my `href` it find me all tags `<a>` with all attributes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Consider using an HTML parser instead.** Regex often isn't powerful enough to parse HTML. For the example you posted, and fairly limited variations of it, the following should work:

`<a[\s\S]*?href="([^"]+)"[\s\S]*?>`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kLfmVm/4/)

Comment: Your regex is not 100% what I want (I need `<a>` which have inside a specific text), but It helped me. I got from your regex `([^\n"]+)` and replaced with `(.*)` from mine, which result `<a .*href="(?<href>[^\n"]+)".*>My Text<\/a>`. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome - good luck with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to locate the link inside the href attribute :

**Regex :**

```
<a .*? `href="(.*?)"`.*?>(?>.*?<\/a>)
```

**Explanation :**

```
.*? ==> anything with non-greedy markup

href="(.*?)" ==> the captured group

(?>.*?<\/a>) ==> loop-ahead for the closed tag
```

**Demo :**
[Here](https://regex101.com/r/S29vpJ/1)