# Extracting url using Regex from email body

Tags: regex

so i've been searching for solutions as to how to extract a particular url from an email body, but many seem to be extensive or a bit confusing. This is the email href:

```
<a href="http://matrix.ms.com/" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://matrix.ms.com/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1591284067791000&amp;usg=AFQjCNGSmpctZFZau9kOCv8xa9Abu8a-uQ">Matrix.ms.com</a>
```

I only want to extract the http://matrix.ms.com/ portion (the link between the quotation marks).
This is sort of how I got the ball rolling but im a bit lost from here:

```
(?<=href\=").*(?="\>)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer help?[regular-expression-for-finding-href-value-of-a-a-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926142/regular-expression-for-finding-href-value-of-a-a-link)

Answer (score -2):

You can use this regex to catch the link:

```
href.+?[\'|\"]+?([^\'|\"]+)?[\'|\"]
```

Working example:
https://regex101.com/r/GtPNW0/1