# Is there a way to automatically convert every href link into a tracking link like Bitly?

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-analytics

I have a large website with many links. I would like to see statistics and analytics for each link. I could use Bitly and manually convert every link into a Bitly link, however, this is a tedious process. Is there a way I can automate this?

Comment: In your own application keep a store of clicks. Then on your links use something like a query string with a referral value (so you know where the user came from), then when your server serves the specific page, increment the count in the database according to the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a script with a regex, that will fetch all your `<a href="">...</a>` and replace them by an already defined array of Bitly links.
Apparently, you can use `<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=(["'])(.*?)\1`, taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15926317/8816585).

Comment: I understand this. However, I would still need to manually create the Bitly links for each href URL. My question was how do I automate this process of generating tracking links?

Comment: You could automate that with something like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer), simulating clicks for you. :D